# Why Eclipse needs to be configure for Lombok?

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok, javaagents

In my Java project, i use Lombok tool to generate getter and setter.
It works perfectly with Maven, without any configuration.

For what reason i need to configure Eclipse for Lombok ?
I already know how to configure Eclipse : https://projectlombok.org/download.html

Why i have to add the following line in my eclipse.ini ?

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Comment: Because lombok isn't a standard library, it actually edits your source code before it is compiled. So Java needs to have it available before it would look for dependencies.

Comment: It usually works out-of-the-box after you install. Supplying custom java agent seems to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The Lombok site states:

```
Lombok copies your source files to another directory, 
replacing all lombok annotations with their desugared form.
```

So configuring is done just because of source code modification. Without "javaagent" would be difficult.

Comment: Why Lombok doesn't just used the java annotation processor ?  
https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/

Comment: Why we don't need to configure anything when we use maven ?

Comment: Because we are smart :)

Answer (score 1):

Lombok [uses Java annotation processor](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/core/AnnotationProcessor.java#L49). So, irrespective of which IDE you use, if Lombok's jar is available for `javac`, your getters and setters get generated and all other functionality of Lombok works as expected.

Maven adds dependent jars (including Lombok's) to `-classpath` parameter of `javac`, so you wouldn't need a Java agent to instrument the code for you.

Comment: I'd like to believe you but I have so far not find the trick to make it work without agent